# Store & index List of Strings in Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am using AppEngine's native Datastore API to store objects in Java.

I have a requirement to search on various items in an object - eg: email address, subject of email, from name etc. It should show the results even for partial input - like real-time searches.

To achieve that, I am tokenizing the items into possible inputs into fragments using StringUtils2.breakdownFragments - the string "Foo Bar" would become: "f", "fo", "foo", "b", "ba", "bar"

What I do not understand is how can I give this list of Strings to be indexed and how can I retrieve them back applying filters?

While using JDO or Objectify, I see it to relatively straight forward but using it via the native API, I do not how to do it.

Entity does not take a list to be stored.

Can it even be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware of exploding indexes. Each list property item gets indexed separately. You will be very limited in the complexity of the queries you can run. I went that road before the advent of the Search API.

If your search feature can tolerate being out of sync for small amount of times, I would suggest using the Search API to implement your feature.

Comment: Thanks. I started looking at Full text API. Just a caveat, it's in beta and that's what it stops me. ALso, I do not understand why is it not just possible to have it index all fields and build indexes and let the developers for that feature instead of having them sync everything entity updates or gets deleted.

Comment: Well, the Search API is a generic service that may not be used in conjunction with the datastore. For instance, you might use the API to index text documents, web pages from a crawler, speech to text conversions, etc. And there's a lot of complexity involved in 'just indexing an entity fields'. How do you want it indexed, how will you search on the fields (and, or, not, conjunctions, disjunctions), how should fields be converted to strings (the search api only indexes text), etc. A really good introduction to the problem is found in the 'Hibernate Search' project add-on to Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `Entity.setProperty()` and pass a `List<String>` as the value.

Comment: This works too. Thanks. But exploding indexes would be a problem.

Comment: Exploding indexes are only a problem when you create multi-property indexes across multiple list properties.  And even then, if you are clever about how you define them, you can avoid exploding indexes.  See this article:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection